# DrRacket - find the longest increasing subsequence

Tags: recursion, scheme, racket

I want to create code for finding LIS. My code doesn't work very well. For example if the input is '(1 3 5 10 9 6 7), output should be '(1 3 5 6 7) but my program return '(1 3 5 10). What am I doing wrong? Have I code binary tree and then find the higher height? Or can I code this program in easiest way?

```
(define (return_sequence N lst)
  (cond
    [(empty? lst) '()]
    [(< N (first lst)) (cons                           
                           (first lst)
                           (return_sequence (first lst) (rest lst))
                           )]
    [else (return_sequence N (rest lst))]
  )
)

(define (find_longest lst1 lst2)
  (cond
    [(empty? lst1) lst2]
    [(empty? lst2) lst1]
    [(< (length lst1) (length lst2)) lst2]
    [else lst1]
  )
)

(define (LIS lst) 
  (cond
    [(empty? lst) '()]
    [else (find_longest
           (cons
            (first lst)
            (return_sequence (first lst) (rest lst)))
           (LIS (rest lst))
          )]
  )
)
```

Comment: How is `(1 3 5 6 7)` a subsequence of `(1 3 5 10 9 6 7)`? IMO the correct answer is `(1 3 5 10)` since after `10` you have `9` which is not increasing and `(9)` and `(6 7)` are shorter than `(1 3 5 10)`.

Comment: @Sylwester The term "subsequence" has a well-known technical meaning. Sequence `a` is a subsequence of sequence `b` iff one can get from `b` to `a` by doing a finite (possibly 0) number of deletions.

Comment: @MarkSaving That must be mathematical definition, however in programming languages we do have functions named subsequence. Eg.  [CL subseq](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_subseq.htm) that acually is CL version of `substring`, but it works across both vectors and lists.

Comment: @Sylwester I need to find the longest possible increasing sequence in array. That is reason why correct answer is (1 3 5 6 7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before we begin, a question. Do you consider `'(1 1)` to be an increasing sequence? For now, I will assume you do not.

First, note that we can simplify `find-longest` as follows:

```lisp
(define (find-longest lst1 lst2)
  (if (<= (length lst1)
          (length lst2))
      lst1
      lst2))
```

This is terribly inefficient, but we won't worry about that for now. It at least looks cleaner than your code.

I assume that you're trying to define `(return_sequence N lst)` to be the longest increasing subsequence of `lst` such that all elements of said subsequence are greater than `N`. I suggest you take a look at exactly what happens when you try `(return_sequence 1 '(4 2 3))`. We should expect the result to be `'(2 3)`, but it is in fact `'(4)`.

You need to think carefully about exactly how you want to handle the case where `(< N (first lst))` and make sure you're not making a silly mistake (spoiler - you are making a silly mistake).

Edit: suppose that `(< N (first lst))`. The longest increasing subsequence of `lst` where all elements are greater than `N` either contains `(first lst)` or doesn't. To find the longest subsequence that doesn't, we compute `(return_sequence N (rest lst))`. To find the longest subsequence that does, we compute `(cons (first lst) (return_sequence (first lst) (rest lst))`. The relevant `cond` clause becomes

```lisp
[(< N (first lst)) (find_longest 
                      (cons (first lst) 
                            (return_sequence (first lst) (rest lst)))
                      (return_sequence N (rest lst)))]
```

and this solves your problem.

On another note, it's extremely helpful to add in the value of `minus-infinity`, with the condition that this value is always less than any other value. In that case, we can just do

```lisp
(define (LIS lst)
   (return_sequence minus-infinity lst))
```

Doing this requires a little bit of cleverness, but it is possible.

In fact, one clever way to add `minus_infinity` is to pass into `return_sequence` not a number `N`, but the function `(lambda (x) (< N x))`. Then, instead of the line `(< N (first list))`, you would instead write `(less_than_N (first list))`. Then, you can `(define (minus_infinity x) #t)`.

It's also possible to create a new symbol using `gensym` and have that be `minus_infinity`. You'd then want to do something rather cheeky like

```lisp
(define minus_infinity (gensym))

(define (return_sequence N lst)
 (let ((< (lambda (a b) (or (equal? a minus_infinity) (< a b)))))
   cond ...)

(define (LIS lst)
  (return_sequence minus_infinity lst))
```

with the cheeky bit being that we're not defining `(<)` recursively - the `<` that occurs in `(lambda (a b) (or (equal? a minus_infinity) (< a b)))` is the original `<`.

Finally, the algorithm you're trying is really slow. It's possible to solve this problem in `O(n log n)` where `n = (length lst)`. Your solution will be an exponential time one, but improving it is highly nontrivial.

Comment: Thanks for response. I know about the bug with finding aa number bugger than the first number in the list, that's why I even asked if I need to create a binary list. I understood from you where I have errors, but I didn't understand how to find the longest possible increasing sequence in the list then.

Comment: @TadeasVasko See my revised answer

Comment: @TadeasVasko Glad I could help.